# Handling Zero Sales in Price Elasticity Linear Regression Analysis

Tags: python, linear-regression, missing-data

I'm currently working on a price elasticity study that involves using linear regression to analyze the impact of competitor and in-house product prices on our sales. The dataset includes sales, price data for both our products and those of our competitors, as well as other relevant variables like past sales.

However, I've run into a challenge when dealing with cases where there are zero sales of a competitor's product. In such situations, I lack competitor price information, making it challenging to assess the influence of their prices on our sales.

Here's an overview of my specific scenario:

**Target Variable:** My sales data is the target variable that I want to predict.

**Features:** The features include prices of our competitors and our products, historical sales data, and various other factors.

**Data Variability:** Since I work with multiple products, there are frequent data gaps and missing values.

Possible solution I have thought but have some problems:

- Creating separate models for every possible combination of products seems impractical and could result in a significant loss of information.
- One approach I've considered is assigning a high price to imply zero sales, but I'm unsure if this is the most appropriate solution.

I suspect that this issue is not unique and that others in the field of price elasticity analysis may have encountered similar challenges. I'm seeking advice and insights from those who have experience with this specific problem. Are there established methods or best practices for addressing this issue, especially when working with multiple products and trying to make the most efficient use of available data?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to effectively manage this particular challenge within the context of a price elasticity analysis.